# Get personal IP address of user machine

Tags: angular, typescript, ip, ip-address

To verify the user is logging in a safe machine I need to take the user machine's personal IP address. After long search I'm not able to find the solution in **Angular 2 with typescript**. How to get the personal IP address?

**NOTE :** Don't need to access the user's notwork IP address.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only

Comment: You can't get the individual user's IP address if they are behind a proxy / firewall / other infrastructure. The IP address is not even guaranteed to be genuine - it is perfectly simple to spoof it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this website that gives a lot of information about your machine : http://freegeoip.net/json/

here is the code to get your personnal IP address using typescript:

```
this._http.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/")
        .map(data => {

            console.log(data.json().ip);
});
```

Comment: This website is producing the network's IP address not personal machine's IP address.

Comment: to get your personal machine's IP address , replace the URL with this one : `https://ipinfo.io` , Hope it helps you

Comment: It also provides the network IP's only.. I understand getting personal IP address is not best practice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please help me to sovle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241799/failed-to-compile-node-modules-macaddress-lib-windows-js-in-angular-5 @MohamedAliRACHID